# DataContext to DataGrid in user control

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, user-controls, datacontext

I have a main window with tabcontrol.
Adding a new tabitem with a user control content.
In the xaml:

```
    <Grid><DataGrid  DataContext="{Binding Path=Patients, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Id"
                                Width="Auto"
                                Binding="{Binding Id}"/>
```

In code behind:
Opening context,

```
 var query = from pp in context.Patients select pp;
 var Patients = query.ToList();        
 TabItem patientsView = new TabItem(); // adding new tabitem
 StackPanel header = new StackPanel
 header.Children.Add(new TextBlock {Text="Patients"});
 patientsView.Header = header;
 patientsView.Content = new ViewDataPatients{DataContext = Patients};
```

It refuses to populate the bind data to the grid.
Any idea where I am doing this wrong?

Comment: this may or may not help http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/683429/Guide-to-WPF-DataGrid-formatting-using-bindings if not do a simple google search on DataContext data binding to a DataGrid..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can't understand why you need such approach, but still. You've set DataContext of your UserControl to Patiense, so DataGrid alreay have this data context, enought the following:

```
<DataGrid DataContext="{Binding}">
```

But this is redundant in your case. To populate DataGrid with data just set ItemsSource:

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

Hope this helps.

King regards, Nazar

Comment: Thanks Nazar!    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}">  solved my issue.